# custom array class doesn't work with jsdoc

Tags: javascript, arrays, class

Hi I am Trying To Use Jsdoc @type tag to define what this constable stores.
Here is my codes

```js
/* eslint-disable no-mixed-spaces-and-tabs */
/* eslint-disable valid-jsdoc */
// eslint-disable-next-line no-unused-vars
// eslint-disable-next-line no-unused-vars

/**
* The Queue class.
*/
module.exports = class Queue extends Array {

    constructor(player) {
        super();
        this.player = player;
    }
    /** Returns the total duration of the queue including the current track. */
    get duration() {
        const current = (this.player.current || {}).length || 0;
        return this.map((track) => track.length).reduce((acc, cur) => acc + cur, current);
    }

    push(...args) {
        const result = super.push(...args);
        // this.player.emit('queueAdd', null);
        return result;
    }

    shift() {
        const result = super.shift();

        // this.player.emit('queueRemove', null);

        return result;
    }

    unshift(...args) {
        const result = super.unshift(...args);

        // this.player.emit('queueAdd', null);

        return result;
    }

    splice(...args) {
        const data = super.splice(...args);
        // this.player.emit('queueRemove', null);

        return data;
    }


    /**
    * Removes an amount of tracks using a start and end index.
    * @param start The start to remove from.
    * @param end The end to remove to.
    */
    removeFrom(start, end) {
       if (isNaN(start)) {
           throw new RangeError(`Queue#removeFrom() Missing "start" parameter.`);
       } else if (isNaN(end)) {
           throw new RangeError(`Queue#removeFrom() Missing "end" parameter.`);
       } else if (start >= end) {
           throw new RangeError(`Queue#removeFrom() Start can not be bigger than end.`);
       } else if (start >= this.length) {
           throw new RangeError(`Queue#removeFrom() Start can not be bigger than ${this.length}.`);
       }
       return this.splice(start, end - start);
    }
    /**
    * Removes a track from the queue. Defaults to the first track.
    * @param [position=0] The track index to remove.
    * @returns The track that was removed, or null if the track does not exist.
    */
    remove(position = 0) {
       return this.splice(position, 1)[0];
    }
    /** Clears the queue. */
    clear() {
       this.splice(0);
    }
    /** Shuffles the queue. */
    shuffle() {
       for (let i = this.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
           const j = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i + 1));
           [this[i], this[j]] = [this[j], this[i]];
       }
    }

};
```

What i am trying to do is

```js
/**
* @type {Queue<TrackClass>}
**/
const queue = new Queue();
```

But My ide (vscode) thinks its undefined/any.
How make it see it as a custom array class storing the TrackClass class?

If I try To do
{TrackClass[]} works
but if i do that it doesn't work. What seems to be the issue here?

Comment: If you try to do TrackClass[] works? where? You must declare you class and then export it using the module.exports syntax. Are you using TypeScript?

Comment: I am using javascript. In typescript it is possible to do what i am doing but not in js, I want to do this in javascript

Comment: if i do 
 @type {TrackClass[]}
const queue = new Queue(); it works but my ide won't detect the Custom Array class additional methods

Comment: why on earth you would want to do that, I do not know. Just use class...then export it at the end of your declaration. that's it